# How to run command on multiple selected objects in maya

Tags: python, for-loop, select, maya

I'm sure this is a total noob question. I'm in Maya and I need to select a whole bunch of objects, then create a joint that is parented under each of those objects.

It works perfectly on a single selected object using this code:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
selection = mc.ls(sl=True)
for all in selection:
    mc.joint()
```

But it fails when I have more than 1 object selected. How can I get my for loop to work on each selected object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The missing step in your script is to re-select each object:

```
import maya.cmds as mc
selection = mc.ls(sl=True)
for each in selection:
    cmds.select(each, r=True)
    mc.joint()
```

The `r=True` flag replaces the current selection so the recently created joints are deselected and the next item in the original is selected.